# Python sys.stdin throws a UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, sys

I'm trying to write a (very) basic web crawler using cURL and Python's `BeautifulSoup` library (since this is much easier to understand than GNU awk and a mess of regular expressions).

Currently, I'm trying to pipe the contents of a webpage to the program with cURL (i.e., `curl http://www.example.com/ | ./parse-html.py`)

For some reason, Python throws a `UnicodeDecodeError` because of an invalid start byte (I've looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095360/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-11-invalid) about invalid start bytes, but did not figure out how to solve the issue from them).

Specifically, I've tried to use `a.encode('utf-8').split()` from the first answer. The second answer simply explained the issue (that Python found an invalid starter byte), though it didn't give a solution.

I've attempted redirecting the output of cURL to a file (i.e., `curl http://www.example.com/ > foobar.html` and modifying the program to accept a file as a command-line argument, though this causes the same `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I've checked, and the output of `locale charmap` is `UTF-8`, which as far as I know, means that my system is encoding characters in `UTF-8` (which makes me especially confused about this `UnicodeDecodeError`.

At the moment, the exact line causing the error is `html_doc = sys.stdin.readlines().encode('utf-8').strip()`. I've tried rewriting this as a for-loop, though I get the same issue.

What exactly is causing the `UnicodeDecodeError` and how should I fix the issue?

**EDIT:**
By changing the line `html_doc = sys.stdin.readlines().encode('utf-8').strip()` to `html_doc = sys.stdin` fixes the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is during reading, *not* encoding; the input resource is simply not encoded with UTF-8, but another encoding. In a UTF-8 shell, you can easily reproduce the problem with

```
$ echo 2¥ | iconv -t iso8859-1 | python3 -c 'import sys;sys.stdin.readline()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

You can read the file (`sys.stdin.buffer.read()`, or `with open(..., 'rb') as f: f.read()`) as binary (you'll get a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binaryseq) object), examine it, and guess the encoding. The actual algorithm to do that [is documented in the HTML standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset).

However, in many cases the encoding is not specified in the file itself, but via the HTTP [`Content-Type` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17). Unfortunately, your invocation of curl does not capture this header. Instead of using curl *and* Python, you can simply use Python only - it already [can download URLs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html). Stealing [the encoding detection algorithm from youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/fe6856b0595b85c8070d7ccc154cd8ac2ff85e2c/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py#L380), we get something like:

```
import re
import urllib.request


def guess_encoding(content_type, webpage_bytes):
    m = re.match(
        r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+\s*;\s*charset="?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"?',
        content_type)
    if m:
        encoding = m.group(1)
    else:
        m = re.search(br'<meta[^>]+charset=[\'"]?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)[ /\'">]',
                      webpage_bytes[:1024])
        if m:
            encoding = m.group(1).decode('ascii')
        elif webpage_bytes.startswith(b'\xff\xfe'):
            encoding = 'utf-16'
        else:
            encoding = 'utf-8'

    return encoding


def download_html(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as urlh:
        content = urlh.read()
        encoding = guess_encoding(urlh.getheader('Content-Type'), content)
        return content.decode(encoding)

print(download_html('https://phihag.de/2016/iso8859.php'))
```

There are also some libraries (though not in the standard library) which support this out of the box, namely [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

I also recommend that you read up on the [basics of what encodings are](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).